# How To Retrieve Image From MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with retrieving an image that recently saved in the database. it instead displays this broken image icon

form page code:

```
<form id "formUpload" action="uploadimage.php" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
<input type="file" name="image" id "image" style="background-color:#000">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<iframe name ="iframe" width="140" height="216">
<img style="min-height: 216; max-width: 140; max-height: 216px;" id="image" />
<br />
<br />
</iframe>
```

upload image code(which is in a different file):
$lastid is used to get the most recent saved image in the database to be displayed on the form page.

```
include("databaseconnect.php");

//file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))
{
    echo "Select Image File: ";   
}

else
{
$image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['imageNAME']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if($image_size==FALSE)
{
echo "thats not an image";
}
else
{
if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblcinema VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '$image', '$image_name', '')"))
{
echo "Upload Image Failed";
}

else
{
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();
echo "<img src=uploadimage.php?id=$lastid>";  
}
}
}
```

Display image into the form page code(also in different file):

```
include("databaseconnect.php");

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['imageID']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblcinema WHERE imageID = $id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $image;
```

and in the database table, i already used type BLOB.

Please help me solve this... as soon as possible!!!
i would highly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to move uploaded file to a particular folder 
by :

```
`move_uploaded_file(file,location);`
```

check what you have got in $image it must be a path to image file then 
You can fetch image by its path:

```
<img style="min-height: 216; max-width: 140; max-height: 216px;" id="image" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the actual image (binary data) into the database, but the `tmp_name` (string). Use `file_get_contents()`, like so:

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the image anywhere

You need to move the image file from temp folder to your uploads folder and store the path to the image in your database

Answer (score 0):

move your uploaded file first then get it by path :

```
if(!isset($file))
{
    echo "Select Image File: ";   
}

else
{

    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['imageNAME']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $uploaddir   = "Directory where files can be store";
    $upload_path =  $uploaddir.'/'.$image_name;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$upload_path));
//other codes goes here
}

to get the value of image :

    <img style="min-height: 216; max-width: 140; max-height: 216px;" id="image" src="folder-path/<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```